# VB install and SYSTEM user

Tags: vb.net, deployment

Hy,
I've create a setup for my vb application with visual studio.
At the end of the install I want to launch the application so i've add a custom action and used the chell to launch it. It's work but... the application is launch as SYSTEM user...
is there a way to launch it in normal user (on win7 as administrator)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the application as an Administrator and launching the application, then it will start under that identity.

Try installing the application as a non Admin user and see under what identity the application launches.

If it still requires Admin access, then look at the privileges requested in your config file.